# I'm stuck trying to add in a For Loop, no idea what to do

Tags: for-loop, addition

I'm trying to create a program that creates a for loop that requires me to enter a specific number of laps driven, followed by the program asking how many seconds each lap took.

The problem here is that I have to add the times from each loop together in order to find the average and I don't know how to add in a For Loop.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
 import time

 laps = int(input("How many laps have been driven? "))

 for seconds in range (laps):
     int (input ("How many seconds did this lap take? "))

 print (seconds)
```

Comment: Don't try to add all of the times at once, instead create a variable representing a running sum, and add them to that one at a time.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got it.